# Nunjucks macro's not found if in nested folders

Tags: macros, nunjucks, client-side-templating

I have the following structure:

**templates**
  - base.njk
**pages**
  - index.njk
**components** //my macro's
    **button**
    - button.njk
    - button.scss

So when I do an import of my macro in my page: 
`{% import 'button/button.njk' as btn %}`
This doesnt work, it loads the button because it doesnt say it can't find the template but when I try to call my macro:
`{{ btn() }}`
It throws an error saying:

> Unable to call "btn", which is not a function

but when its not in the 'button' folder it works.

I just want to know if there's a way of maintaining this structure and get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{{ btn.your-macros-name() }}
```

or

```
{% from 'button/button.njk' import your-macros-name as btn %}
{{ btn() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wirte your code like this
you can import this in any .njk or .html file except button.njk

{% import "button.njk" as btn %}